# AMD Phenom II X2 555 BE, core unlock suddenly not working?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, amd-phenom

I've had a **Phenom II X2 555 BE** for around 2 - 3 years. When I got it, I immediately core unlocked it with my **ECS A880GM-A3 mobo**, which makes it turn into a **Phenom II X4 B55**. A few days ago, I **installed Windows 7 64 bit** to compensate for my 4 gigs of ram. When I start my system with its cores unlocked, it will restart after the BIOS screen. If I disable the core unlock, it boots to OS just fine. My question is:

- Does 64 bit OS makes a difference in core unlocking?
- Does my 3rd and 4th core burnt out?

Also extra info: I tried core unlocking but keeping the 3rd and 4th core disabled and it still won't boot into OS. Could it be motherboard problems?
Sorry for bad English. I will try to give additional information if needed. Thanks!
Also it is worth mentioning I'm no computer expert but I tried to make my explanation as short as possible.

I also asked my question on TomsHardware, but I had no answer till now so I decided to ask here too.

anyone...?